# Loosely Inheritance purpose

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I found the following interesting method in the babel compiler in and im totally new to js:

```
  export default function _inheritsLoose(subClass, superClass)  {
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass.prototype);
    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
    subClass.__proto__ = superClass;   } ;
```

So I assumed, its to generate loosely coupled inheritance between two objects and I tried the following:

1. I created two simple objects

   ```
   class Human{
       constructor(name, surname){
        this.Name = name;
        this.Surname = surname;
       }

       rennen(){
           console.log("Ich renne...");
       }
   }

   class Superhuman{
       constructor(age, weight) {
           this.Age = age;
           this.Weight = weight;
       }

       ausruhen(){
           console.log("Ich ruhe aus...");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Created them and logged prototype

   ```
   var a = new Human("Max", "Mustermann");
   var b = new Superhuman(4, 80);

   console.log("Human");
   console.log(Human.prototype);

   console.log("Superhuman");
   console.log(Superhuman.prototype);
   ```

As expected they have their own props and methods.

3. I used the _inheritsLoose method that i found

   ```
   Human.prototype = Object.create(Superhuman.prototype);
   Human.prototype.constructor  = Superhuman;
   Human.__proto__ = Superhuman;
   ```

and expected that the following line has to be true

```
   // Expecting its true now???
   console.log(Human.prototype === Superhuman.prototype);
```

and

```
   // Expecting its available in Human now???
   Superhuman.prototype.fly = () => console.log("I fly....");
```

But it did not work. So my question is what is the purpose of the _inheritsLoose method and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot change the `prototype` property of a class.

Comment: And why babel is doing that?

Comment: How do you know that the parameters `subClass` and `superClass` are actually classes?

Comment: Naming and u call prototype on it.